Finding any vertex on an implicit convex polytope?
Assume you are given k half spaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that you know form a closed polytope.
And say they are labeled $P_i$ with $i \in [0, k-1]$.
I am looking for an efficient way of finding a set $T \subset \{P_i\}, |T| \geq 3$ such that the intersection of all planes in $T$ is a corner of the polytope.
In English, I want to find any subset of the input planes such that their intersection is guaranteed to be a corner of the convex polytope that they form.
To the people saying that the Phase 1 methodology does not assume the axial planes are part of the constraints. Please provide me with a source, because despite comments insisting that textbooks don't make this assumption, all resources I ever find on the topic do make it.
For example:
NCSU, assumption on slide 50
U Waterloo, assumption on the very first page
Polytecnic of Milan, assumption on every example
EPFL, assumption on the first page
It is not helpful to tell me to find something and when I explain that the resources I can find do not contain the proper generalized version of the problem insist that they do.
Please provide me with a source that does not make the assumption that the axial planes are part of the constraints.

Phase I of the simplex method does this for you.

@BrianBorchers Whenever I see the simplex method described in a textbook they do the arbitrary assumption that three of the planes will be the axial planes orthogonal to the x,y,z planes.
But I cannot make this assumption. Perhaps you are talking of a more generalized setting than the one I am familiar with? Do you have a source I could look at?

There are many different ways of setting up a phase I problem depending on the form of the original system of equations and inequalities.  If you start with a system of linear inequalities, this can be converted into a system of linear equations by introducing "slack variables" that are non-negative.

@BrianBorchers. The problem is not set up as a system of linear inequalities. It is set up as a set of vectors representing the normal directions of the planes and whose norm represents the distance along the normal at which the plane is.

That means that you already have a system of equations for your problem.

"a set of vectors representing the normal directions of the planes and whose norm represents the distance along the normal at which the plane is" -- that is one way in which you can represent a set of linear inequalities.

As Brian Borchers already mentions in a comment, what you are looking for is called "phase 1" in solving a linear optimization problem with the simplex method. The simplex method starts with a vertex of the polytope and then moves from one vertex to another that is better until it cannot make progress any more -- that's the solution. The tricky part is to find a feasible vertex (any feasible vertex!) to start with, and that's what's called "phase 1".
Every textbook will walk you through how phase 1 is set up. It involves solving a dual problem that has a specific structure. In particular, the dual problem has the origin as a feasible vertex, and then you just need to apply the simplex algorithm to the dual problem. The solution of the dual problem is a vertex of the original problem (under some reasonable assumptions).

The question is not about the simplex method. As mentioned in the comments, textbooks (at least those I have been exposed to), always assume that the solution is non negative, thus magically adding every coordinate plane to the system and trivially setting one of the vertices to be the origin. This is not something I can assume.

No, textbooks don't make that assumption. It is true for the dual problem, and so the original is a feasible vertex of the dual problem. Then you apply the simplex algorithm to the dual problem (=phase 1), and the solution of the dual problem is a vertex of the primal problem, and then you run the simplex algorithm a second time for the primal problem. In both cases, you have a feasible starting vertex: for the dual problem, it is the origin; for the primal problem, it is the solution of the dual problem.
